# How do I get records from ohter languages in a backend Modul

Tags: javascript, extbase, typo3-8.x

I try to list records from other languages in a backend module. So far I tried this

```
    public function findAllByLang($lang)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching(
            $query->logicalAnd(
                [
                    $query->equals('sysLanguageUid', $lang)
                ]
            )
        );
        return $query->execute();
    }
```

But I got an error from FrontendGroupRestriction.php
Here is the complete error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/FrontendGroupRestriction.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/FrontendGroupRestriction.php(36): explode(',', NULL) #1 /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php(3968): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\FrontendGroupRestriction->__construct() #2 /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/AbstractRestrictionContainer.php(101): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\...') #3 /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/FrontendRestrictionContainer.php(47): TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\AbstractRestrictionContainer->createRestriction('TYPO3\CMS\Core\...') #4  in /typo3_src-8.7.27/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/FrontendGroupRestriction.php on line 36

**Can anybody help please?**

Answer (score 0):

My actual solution is this, and works:

```
public function findAllByLang($lang)
{

    $table = 'tx_gesurveys_domain_model_invitation';
    /** @var QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
        ->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);
    $data = $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from($table)
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->eq('sys_language_uid', $lang))
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

    return $data;
}
```